# Can i remove multi class from a single id

Tags: jquery, class

i want to remove a multi class in jQuery, i have a id element like this

```
<div id="progress">content here</div>
```

somtimes its can look like this

```
<div id="progress" class="progress progress-danger">content here</div>
```

or its can look like this

```
<div id="progress" class="progress progress-warning">content here</div>
```

my problem is if I want to remove all class `progress-*` from it.

I need to remove it X line of types I got my progress class.

like this

```
$('#progress').removeClass('progress-danger');
$('#progress').removeClass('progress-warning');
```

can somebody maybe help me,

Comment: Is there a fixed reasonably small number of `progress-*` class names or can it be anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass more than one class name to the removeClass function:

```
$('#languageProgress').removeClass('progress-danger progress-warning');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nygSe/1/

Answer (score 3):

`.attr()` can take a function as second argument, so using that you can parse the className for each element found using RegExp, f.ex:

```
$('#progress').attr('class', function() {
    return this.className.replace(/progress-[a-z]+/g,'');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nVLzF/1/

Comment: The best answer so far, just a small problem, this will fail if you have <div id="progress" class="progress progress-warning anotherclass">content here</div>.
The space between the progress and anotherclass will be lost. Should work for OP though

Comment: @NoBBy True, it’s probably best to just skip the `\s` since the interpretor doesn’t care about spaces. It was just for looks! (edited)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all class names and loop over them:

```
var $progress = $('#progress');
var classList = $progress[0].className.split(/\s+/);
$.each(classList, function(index, item){
    if (item.indexof('progress-') == 0) {
       $progress.removeClass(item);
    }
});
```

If you don't just want to check a single element you could use the selector from @Alessandro Minoccheri's answer and loop with `.each()`:

```
var $progress = $("div[class^='progress-'],div[class*='progress-']");
$progress.removeClass(function(index, classList){
    var item = this;
    var removeClasses = [];
    $.each(classList.split(/\s+/), function(index, className){
        if (className.indexOf('progress-') === 0) {
            removeClasses.push(className);
        }
    });
    return removeClasses.join(' ');
});​
```

Comment: Instead of `$progress.each(function(){` you could also use `$progress.removeClass(function(){ ...` and so on. but be sure the class names are returned as a result :)  [.removeClass() Doc](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("div[class^='progress'],div[class*='progress']").removeClass();
```

This will remove class elements where the class starts by "progress" and elements that contain a class stated by "progress".

Comment: but how about to leave other class names?

Comment: this remove all class that start with progress

Comment: [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

Comment: He has to select the div and the div that contain progress- and it works

Comment: No @AlessandroMinoccheri, because there may be other classes on the same element which should not be removed. (`<div class="progress-test someOtherClass">`)